# vue.js reactivity not working for object array

Tags: vue.js

vue.js reactivity not working for object array.

```
html .. 
<div v-if="a && a.arr" v-for="k in a.arr">
  {{k.name}}
</div>

data .. 
{
   a:{}
} 
methods ..
{
 updateA(){
   a.arr=[];
   a.arr.push({name:'abc'});
 },

 updateA2(){ 
   let b = a.arr && a.arr[0];
   if(b){
    b.name='xyz';
    // Vue.set(b,'name','xyz');
   }
 }

}
```

Even tried
Vue.set or this.$set but it doesn't help

Comment: In your data, use `a: { arr: [] }`, declare `arr` in `a`.

Comment: What you mean by "_not working_"? What is the current behaviour? What is the expected behaviour? Please also read through [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Psidom answer may help, another approach would be to use set in `updateA2` like
`Vue.set(a, 'arr', []);`

Comment: Your snippet works as expected - there should be no reactivity the way you use it

Answer (score 0):

You should try like this:

```html
html .. 
<div v-if="a && a.arr" v-for="k in a.arr">
  {{k.name}}
</div>

data()
{
  return {
   a: {
     arr: [],
   }
  };
} 
methods:
{
 updateA(){
   a.arr=[];
   a.arr.push({name:'abc'});
 },

 updateA2(){ 
   let b = a.arr && a.arr[0];
   if(b){
    this.$set(b,'name','xyz');
   }
 }

}
```